# rospack Error: package 'script' not found

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am trying to run `rosrun script forward.py` but it gives me an error saying `[rospack] Error: package 'script' not found`

In my bashrc I've added these lines:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /home/hassan/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/home/catkin_ws:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/hassan/catkin_ws
```

What could be the reason?
I am following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwTnY-ZqNcM&t=102s

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons:

- You haven't compiled all your projects in the workspace, to fix it go to your workspace `cd ~/catkin_ws` then execute `catkin_make`. If it works and you don't have compilation errors, source your workspace `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, then re-try.
- When you are typing `rosrun script forward.py`, you expect to launch the script forward.py from the package script. Check if your folder `~/catkin_ws/src/script` exists, if not this cannot work!